# Splice is not working on my production but working on localhost

Tags: javascript, typescript, console

I am trying to splice my string but it is not working on my live server on dev server it is working. This is image of my dev and live server's console. Right console is my dev console and left side is my live console.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzkO8.jpg

What could be the problem i am unable to understand.

This is my code

`"1731354".splice(7-3,0,',')`

Thanks.

Comment: There is no `String.prototype.splice` ?

Comment: Then why is it working on DEV console. On local in my console and also in my code it works perfectly fine but on live it does not works

Comment: Is there code in one version that creates that prototype method? Otherwise there is no reason it should work anywhere. Open your browser console on this page and run it, will get same error

Comment: No. It is angular code and I have done nothing like creating a proptotype method

Comment: Even if it were and array, the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: What does `7-3` mean? What is the expected result? `"17,31354"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`splice` is not a `string` method `array` have only this property.You can add `splice` to string like this.

```js
String.prototype.splice = function(index,num,...newItems){
 let str = this.split('');
 str.splice(index,num,...newItems);
 return str.join('');
}
console.log("123456".splice(1,1," first "," second "," third "));
console.log("123456".splice(1,3));
```